# Expected expression error

Tags: cocoa, xcode4.2

What does this `Expected expression` error mean on this line of code:

`[super setNilValueForKey:key];`

Code:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    expectedRaise = 5.0;
    personName = @"New Person";
    return self;    
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [personName release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqual:@"expectedRaise"])
    {
        [self setExpectedRaise:0.0];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setNilValueForKey:key];
    }
}
@synthesize personName;
@synthesize expectedRaise;

@end
```

.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject
{
    NSString *personName;
    float expectedRaise;
}

@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *personName;
@property (readwrite) float expectedRaise;

@end
```

Comment: What does your .h file look like

Answer (score 0):

If you really got

```
[super setNilValueForKey:<#key#>];
```

in your code, the solution should be as simple as

```
[super setNilValueForKey:key];
```

Comment: Ha. That would be nice but no. It was pasting the markup from Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

`isEqual` is the wrong method since I wanted to compare to a string value `isEqualToString` is correct.

```
 - (void)setNilValueForKey:(NSString *)key
    {
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"expectedRaise"])
        {
            [self setExpectedRaise:0.0];
        }
        else
        {
            [super setNilValueForKey:key];
        }
    }
```